# Why does the code say good morning even if the hour is 18.24

Tags: python, if-statement, logic

Why is this still saying good morning if the hour is 18.24?

Code:
[image: Picture of the code]

Sorry for my bad English!

Comment: Images of code are [not acceptable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/10077). Please read [How Do I Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: 18.24 is greater than 5 and so the first condition is met.

Comment: Your tests are evaluated in order, from top to bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says "Good Morning!" because your first conditional checks to see if `hour >= 5`, in which case, `18.24 >= 5` is indeed True, hence the conditional triggers.

You want to **reorder your conditionals** to be in the reverse order. Something like:

```
if hour >= 20:
   do something...
elif hour >= 17:
   do something...
elif hour >= 14.5:
   do something...
...
```

In this way, it will only trigger when `18.24 >= 17` and only output `Good Evening`

---

In the future, instead of adding code snippets as an image, you can add them as a code block like I did. You can see it in the edit tools.

Comment: Similar to how I just showed it: Make your first if statement to be for when greater than 20, your second to be greater than 17. third to be greater than 14.5, fourth to be greater than 12 and the last to be greater than 5. Basically do your entire thing in the reverse order

Comment: Okay Ty so much i did it

Comment: No worries, if my solution helped you, you can give it an upvote and set it as the correct answer for the question.